# How use full text TNTSearch facade

Tags: php, laravel, full-text-search

I tried TNTSearch, but the results are only for the complete words. For example, the phrase `Facilis dolorem` gives me all combinations of records with the word `facilis` or word `dolorem.`

How can I do to the search with TNTSearch in Laravel?

```sql
LIKE %lore%
```

If I type `lore,` I don't get the records that have the word `lore` in the middle.

Comment: You can use Scout and Algolia Packages?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response  ...but my project is in laravel 5.2 and If I use the angolia  Hacker plan I must display a small Algolia logo in the search results.... My project is ready with tntsearch but when I done some test at the end I find this little problem...I thinked easy to correct but I spent many days unsuccessfully to try to find a solution

Comment: sorry i am not clear right now that what is your actual question what you get next to search ? please update your question accordingly

Comment: OK, I try again to find a solution so thanks for your attention...have a nice day

Comment: I have same problem- you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable fuzzy search via config like mentioned in the docs:

```
'tntsearch' => [
'storage'  => storage_path(), //place where the index files will be stored
'fuzziness' => env('TNTSEARCH_FUZZINESS', false),
'fuzzy' => [
    'prefix_length' => 2,
    'max_expansions' => 50,
    'distance' => 2
],
```

],

ie. if this is your config set you variable TNTSEARCH_FUZZINESS in .env to true and you should get the results you expect.

Also, if you already have indexes created which seems like you do you'll have to reindex the content in order for fuzzines to kick in...

Comment: "doesn't work" is not much of a description :), give us some more info and maybe someone can help you...

Answer (score 0):

mine same issue not solved and finally used other good alternate:
[laravel-scout-mysql-driver](https://github.com/YABhq/laravel-scout-mysql-driver)
try it
but exactly answer for your question:
you must use `*lore*` in your query. more documentation for queries:
[Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it via add `'asYouType' => false,` in `config\scout.php`.
my code is :

```
'tntsearch' => [
        'storage'  => storage_path(), //place where the index files will be stored
        'fuzziness' => true,
        'fuzzy' => [
            'prefix_length' => 2,
            'max_expansions' => 50,
            'distance' => 2
        ],
        'asYouType' => false,
    ],
```